# Android error while adding AdMob

Tags: android, firebase, admob

I have a problem with ads from AdMob. I do everything as written [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/admob/android/quick-start).

Here is my code:

Graddle:

```
    apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 25
    buildToolsVersion "25.0.2"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.chesshorse.chesshorse"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 25
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        jackOptions {
            enabled true
        }
    }
    buildTypes {
//        release {
//            minifyEnabled false
//            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
//        }
        debug {
            debuggable true
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        targetCompatibility 1.8
        sourceCompatibility 1.8
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.1.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:25.1.1'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-ads:10.2.0'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'

}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

.

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.2.3'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.0.0'
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

Graddle sync corectly, but when i compile my app and run in debugger app is immediately closing with this error:

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
              Process: com.chesshorse.chesshorse, PID: 2260
              java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: No static method zzb(Ljava/lang/Object;Ljava/lang/Object;)Ljava/lang/Object; in class Lcom/google/android/gms/common/internal/zzac; or its super classes (declaration of 'com.google.android.gms.common.internal.zzac' appears in /data/app/com.chesshorse.chesshorse-2/base.apk)
                  at com.google.firebase.provider.FirebaseInitProvider.zza(Unknown Source)
                  at com.google.firebase.provider.FirebaseInitProvider.attachInfo(Unknown Source)
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.installProvider(ActivityThread.java:5853)
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.installContentProviders(ActivityThread.java:5445)
```

Has anyone encountered this error? I look at other stack questions, but none helped. Could anyone tell me where I made a mistake?

Comment: Maybe you missed something. https://github.com/firebase/quickstart-android/tree/master/admob

Comment: Does the device or emulator you are using for testing have version 10.2.98 of Google Play Services installed?

Comment: @qbix How Do You Know which version I use?
How to check this? I try with android 6.0 and Nexus 6 aPI 25

Comment: Use _Settings_ > _Application Manager_; scroll to find Google Play Services; click on it to see App Info including version number.